# How can I omit controllers for two models in rails 3 routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm building a rails3 application and at the moment I have the following line in my routes.rb file:

```
get "/:id" => 'tapes#show'
```

In other words, you can show a **Tape** using `website.com/tapes/1` and also by `using website.com/1` 
(I am also using friendly_id gem so the user sees in fact a friendly URL in the form of `website.com/tapename`)

Now, what I would like to achieve is to do the same thing for **Users** pages. So instead of showing a User page using `website.com/users/alex` I want to be able to also use `website.com/alex`.

Is there a way to implement this 'users' logic in routes.rb **together with the existing 'tapes'** rule and somehow set a priority?
So if someone accesses `website.com/alex` my app would search if there is a **User** record with id  'alex' and if none is found then look for a **Tape** with id 'alex'.

Could I use some kind of Advanced Constraints in routes?
Any ideas?

Many thanks for the help,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Rails would have no way to determine which controller you were trying to access.  The only way that this would be possible, is if either:

1. you could determine which model it would resolve to based upon some regular expression on the name.
   or
2. You knew that user names and tape names never conflicted, and were willing to suffer the cost of hitting the database to resolve the correct controller.

This is probably a bad idea for a number of reasons, it would have performance implications, it also doesn't conform to `RESTful` principles, and it would probably be confusing to users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply idbentley. I was wondering if I could implement the logic in the **Tapes** controller, i.e. only if @tape is not found based on the provided id then search if this id corresponds to a user and if so redirect accordingly. Given my application it is safe to assume that tapes will be accessed far more frequently than users. Would that `if` statement significantly affect performance?

Comment: Also, I would like to offer users the option of easily sharing their profile with the public, so it makes sense to remove the /users/ part from their URL. Same with the Tapes model. Just explaining my reasoning..

Comment: You certainly could do this, yes.  Something like `if Tape.find_by_name tape_name` will do the conditional, and if no such `Tape` exists, use the `redirect_to` function to pass it along.  However, as I said above, this will add an unnecessary database call to each request.  The performance implications are probably not a big deal.  I would still advise against it: `website.com/user/alex`  is just as readable as `website.com/alex`, and requires no hackery.  Finally, if you chose to do this, be sure to document it, because it will be confusing to future developers.